# Getting production error readiness for iot edge on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I installed Iotedge on my raspberry pi two weeks ago with no problems by following the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux

This week i turned my raspberry pi on and I am now getting the following error when i run iotedge check. I am also getting a 406 error when i check its status in the IoT Hub
Error:  *"production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem-Error
  Could not check current state of edgeAgent container
         production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem-Error
  Could not check current state of edgeHub container"*

When i run it with --verbose, i get:

*"production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem-Error
 The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem. 
Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices"*

If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

**Updated errors after I linked the module storage to device storages:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53vEu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Would you share edge agent and hub twin properties defined in azure portal? Remember to remove secret/password/connection string before sharing.

Comment: I'm not sure what properties you are talking about, would you mind being a little more specific please on how to access them?

Answer (score -1):

The production readiness logs are Warnings and you can ignore them if you are just doing tests on an experimental scenario. These warnings will not impact the outcome of [the tutorial you followed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux).

When you're ready to take your IoT Edge solution from development into production, make sure that it's configured for ongoing performance like described here: [Prepare to deploy your IoT Edge solution in production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist#set-up-host-storage-for-system-modules)